# Two stringlists and foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI receives two strings, one containing the display values (names), one containing the hidden values (emails).

Before, it only received one string, over which it used a foreach, and I am unsure how to get it to work with two, **how to fill "name" from "nameslist"**:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public AjaxAnswer BatchUserCreate(string email, string names) {
    string[] emaillist = email.Split('\n');
    string[] nameslist = names.Split('\n');
    foreach(string email in emaillist) {
        db.AddParameter("@email",email);
        db.AddParameter("@name",name);
        int newId = db.ExecuteScalar(userInsQuery);
    }
    return new AjaxAnswer(newId);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zip the two lists together

```
var nameEmailPairs = emaillist.Zip(namelist, (email,name)=>new{email,name});
```

You can then `foreach` over *that*, which will have items with a name and an email.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Zip, but what happens if there isn't a 1 to 1 match between the name and the email?

Comment: The question is... how should the routine handle it?   That will require a modification to the answer.

Comment: @PeterM `Zip` would ignore redundant values from the longer sequence. You can use `ZipLongest` extension method from MOreLinq

Comment: I prefer a simple for loop, however, it's good as well. People sometimes use LINQ like they must to.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I would expect that `Zip` would be the preferable semantics here; as it appears that both values are needed for the query, and that it wouldn't work without both values.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási And I prefer `Zip`.  You're free to use a `for` loop when you have this problem, if you want.

Comment: @Servy totally agree, I'm just giving the options. Maybe Alexander would change that behavior in the future

Comment: @PeterM It stops yielding items whenever the shortest sequence has ended.

Comment: With for loop you need to call `Math.Min(namelist.Length, emaillist.Length)` to achieve the same behavior as `Zip`

Comment: @Servy, of course, didn't mean it at you personally. Just experienced several times that people simply don't know what's happening behind a nice and comfortable LINQ call. I don't think it's a good trend.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a guarantee that these lists are in same order - use plain for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<emaillist.Length; i++) {
    string email = emaillist[i];
    string name = namelist[i];
    ...
```

Or you can use LINQ with `Zip`:

```
var records = emaillist.Zip(namelist, (email, name) => new {email, name});
foreach(var r in records) {
    string email = r.email;
    string name = r.name;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing *foreach* loop to *for* loop:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public AjaxAnswer BatchUserCreate(string email, string names) {
    string[] emaillist = email.Split('\n');
    string[] nameslist = names.Split('\n');

    // You should declare "newId" somewhere here 
    // if you want to return it via "new AjaxAnswer(newId)" 
    int newId = 0;

    // if emaillist and nameslist have diffrent lengths 
    // let's take minimal length
    int n = Math.Min(nameslist.Length, emaillist.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      db.AddParameter("@email", emaillist[i]);
      db.AddParameter("@name", nameslist[i]);
      newId = db.ExecuteScalar(userInsQuery);
    }

    return new AjaxAnswer(newId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `for` loop instead, something like this could help:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public AjaxAnswer BatchUserCreate(string email, string names) {
    string[] emaillist = email.Split('\n');
    string[] nameslist = names.Split('\n');
    for(int i = 0; i!=emaillist.Length; ++i) {
        db.AddParameter("@email", emaillist[i]);
        db.AddParameter("@name", nameslist.Length > i ? nameslist[i] : "No name");
        int newId = db.ExecuteScalar(userInsQuery);
    }
    return new AjaxAnswer(newId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of both arrays (emaillist & nameslist) is equal, you should use a for loop instead of a foreach loop:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public AjaxAnswer BatchUserCreate(string email, string names) {
    string[] emaillist = email.Split('\n');
    string[] nameslist = names.Split('\n');

    for(int i = 0; i < emaillist.Length; i++) {
        db.AddParameter("@email",emaillist[i]);
        db.AddParameter("@name",namelist[i]);
        int newId = db.ExecuteScalar(userInsQuery);
    }
    return new AjaxAnswer(newId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this work around hope it will help

```
for(int i =0 ; i< emaillist .count; i++)
{
    db.AddParameter("@email",emaillist[i]);
    db.AddParameter("@name",nameslist[i]);
    int newId = db.ExecuteScalar(userInsQuery);
}
```